# How to show superscripted or subscripted characters in an XML attribute

Tags: xml

I'm working on a maskdesigner with VS2015 and WPF.
I can serialize the masklayouts from that designer to a XML and save it as a string in the database.
Existing masklayouts can be reloaded in the designer by reading and deserializing the XML-string.

In the masklayouts i'm using some custom controls with dependencyproperties.
In the XML-string these properties are serialized as attributes of the custom control nodes.
One of these attributes is called "DisplayText" and contains texts of type string.
In old data from my customer there are sometimes values which contains superscripted or subscripted characters.

Is it possible to show superscripted or subscripted characters in an XML attribute using UTF-8?
Per example i got in one of the nodes:

```
DisplayText="U_{a}"
```

The result shall be the equivalent to the following HTML example (Big U followed by a subscripted A):

```html
U<sub>a</sub>
```

Further i should say that i got attributes like the example above in a string containing a XML-file which i want to deserialze by XMLSerializer.
In that case the follwing solution would not work in my XML:

```
DisplayText="U<sub>a</sub>"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `<sub>` is a tag like any other, that happens to induce a particular kind of formatting when parsed by HTML browsers. This is completely orthogonal to XML. You can *declare* these syntaxes to be equivalent, if you like, but then it's still up to *you* to produce markup for formatting. Because you can't include tags in attributes, consider making `DisplayText` an element instead. This would make nesting tags natural and it would also allow you to mix in things like MathML (if subscripts aren't the only thing you need).

Comment: In general, if you want to format your XML visually, consider using an XML stylesheet, which could transform attribute text like this into an appropriate sequence of HTML tags for display (although XSLT does have a considerable learning curve).

Comment: @JeroenMostert : Sorry but i can't make an element of the attribute. I have edited my question to explain why.

Comment: You could try to get the [Unicode characters for subscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts) to work for you, provided whatever is displaying the data can handle them. Ultimately, though, how a string is to be interpreted for display purposes isn't up to the XML document, it's up to *you*. Consider the comparable question "how do I get this part of the text to display in blue, using UTF-8"? Well, you don't, since you just can't encode that sort of display instruction in the values themselves -- that's handled by whatever's interpreting the string.